# Trouble organizing Python library for import to behave in expected manner

Tags: python

I've had a lot of trouble figuring out a key point about how the import mechanism works, and how this relates to organizing packages.

Suppose I've written two or more unrelated, reusable libraries.  (I'll use "library" informally as a collection of code and resources, including tests and possibly data, as opposed to a "package" in the formal Python sense.)  Here are two imaginary libraries in a parent directory called "my_libraries":

```
my_libraries/
├── audio_studio
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── distortion.py
│   │   ├── filter.py
│   │   └── reverb.py
│   └── test
│       └── test_audio.py
└── picasso_graphics
    ├── src
    │   ├── brushes.py
    │   ├── colors.py
    │   └── easel.py
    └── test
        └── test_picasso.py
```

I'm hoping to accomplish all three of the following, all of which seem to me to be normal practice or expectation:

**1. MAIN LIBRARY CODE IN SUBDIRECTORY**

For neatness of library organization, I want to put the library's core code in a subdirectory such as "src" rather than at the top-level directory.  (My point here isn't to debate whether "src" in particular is a good naming approach; I've read multiple pages pro and con.  Some people appear to prefer the form foo/foo, but I think I'd have the same problem I'm describing with that too.)

**2. ADD TO $PYTHONPATH JUST ONCE**

I'd like to be able to add "my_libraries" to $PYTHONPATH or sys.path just once.  If I add a new library to "my_libraries", it's automatically discoverable by my scripts.

**3. NORMAL-LOOKING import STATEMENTS**

I'd like to be able import from these libraries into other projects in a normal-looking way, without mentioning the "src" directory:

```
   import picasso_graphics.brushes
   OR
   from picasso_graphics import brushes
```

**HOW TO DO THIS?**

Despite much reading and experimentation, I haven't been able to find a solution which satisfies all three of these criteria.  The closes I've gotten is to create a `picasso_graphics/__init__.py` file containing the following:

```
   base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
   src_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, "src")
   sys.path.insert(0, src_dir)
```

This almost does what I want, but I have to break up the imports into two statements, so that the `__init__.py` file executes with the first import:

```
   import picasso_graphics
   import brushes
```

Am I making a wrong assumption here about what's possible?  Is there a solution which satisfies all three of these criteria?

Comment: Removing the `src` directories and having your source move up one level would be a simple way to fulfil your needs if you can accept the difference to your preferences

Comment: you can add `__init__.py` file in all the directories to make them modules, that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want, Sean, is most likely what is called a [namespace project](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/); Use a tool called [pyscaffold](https://pypi.org/project/PyScaffold/) to help with writing the boilerplate. Each project should have a setup.cfg with all your project dependencies. Once you have that, create a virtual environment for your project, then install each with ... (inside the environment).

```
pip install -e audio-studio

pip install -e picasso-graphics
```

Installing your project into your virtual environment will cause your imports to behave as you want -- between projects.

This is a bit of overhead to get started, I know, but these are skills you want to have sooner or later. Setup.cfg, virtual environments, and pip install -e is a magical pattern that just makes things work where other approaches will drive you mad.

Below is a simple example project I created using pyscaffold. Notice there is a package below src and that src does not have an **init**.py. That is a decision made by the pyscaffold folks to help ease import confusion - you should likely adopt it.

```
    my_libraries/
├── audio-studio
│   ├── AUTHORS.rst
│   ├── CHANGELOG.rst
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── README.rst
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   ├── setup.py
│   ├── src
│   │   └── audio_studio
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── skeleton.py
│   └── tests
│       ├── conftest.py
│       └── test_skeleton.py
└── picasso-graphics
    ├── AUTHORS.rst
    ├── CHANGELOG.rst
    ├── LICENSE.txt
    ├── README.rst
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── setup.cfg
    ├── setup.py
    ├── src
    │   └── picasso_graphics
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── skeleton.py
    └── tests
        ├── conftest.py
        └── test_skeleton.py
```

Comment: incidentally, you only need the individual setups if you want the ability to independently install. Pyscaffold has a namespace option which you will find will create the project slightly differently. It is the install -e part that is the key to making your imports work, it moves symbolic links to your project into your site packages folder in the virtual environment. It will behave as if you did a pip install from pypi.